# Prevent QWebEngineView to open new browser tab

Tags: pyqt, plotly

I am trying to implement plotly in pyqt, using following code I have rendering of figure in pyqt app and also opens new web browser tab displaying same figure. How to prevent opening new browser tab?

```
fig7 = go.Figure(data=
        go.Contour(
            z=X,
            x=Y, # horizontal axis
            y=Z # vertical axis
        ))

self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
self.layout.addWidget(self.browser)
self.browser.setHtml(fig7.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
fig7.show()
```

I tryed googling this problem, but find nothing

Comment: Maybe because you called `fig7.show()`?